# Airplane radar tracking

Tags: kalman-filter

I am new to Kalman filter and I am trying to implement a model that tracks an airplane. I have data of position and velocity in two dimensions for every second of the movement and a moving radar that detects the airplane and will "see" it again after 5 seconds. As I am going to "miss" measurement input for the time that the radar is moving how can I assure that the model will work ( I want the model to predict the state of the airplane for every second)? What shall I input for the measurement at the time when the radar is moving as I don't have the data for the airplane's actual position?

Comment: For the calculations you need to use the steps of 5 seconds - no meaning to intermediate prediction from the Kalman filter point of view.